# Menu draggable elements to add new content to page's body

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

My objective is to have a page with side menu on the left and a empty div on the right (call it #rightdiv).
I want to do drag menu elements and drop them into #rightdiv, and this should create a new div with a page (web app) loaded on it 
relative to the elements dragged and should positionate the div in the #rightdiv, and this up to 4 elements.
It should be possible to remove a div, resizing other divs.

This is a screenshot of what I want to get.

[image]

Obviously I don't expect a solution, I ask you if you know functionalities, libraries or examples
that could help me to find the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can achieve this, by using jsplumb or only jquery

Comment: could you link me some example of jsplumb (if you have it)?

Comment: ok i'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a code who allow you to drag and drop from a `div` to another one.

To make the element resizable, you can use `.resizable()` from jquery.

To be able to delete the elements, you must add a `<button>` on the element and hide or delete the element when clicking this button

```js
$('.draggable').draggable({
  helper: "clone",
});


$('#diagramZone').droppable({
  accept: ".startEventClass, .userTaskClass, .endEventClass",
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    dragE1 = ui.helper.clone();
    dragE1.draggable({
      containment: "#diagramZone",
    });
    $(dragE1).removeClass("startEventClass");
    $(dragE1).addClass("startEventClass");
    if (ui.draggable[0].id) {
      dragE1.appendTo('#diagramZone');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.startEventClass {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.userTaskClass {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.endEventClass {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: solid 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#diagramZone {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="startEvent" class="draggable startEventClass">

</div>

<div id="userTask" class="draggable userTaskClass"></div>

<div id="endEvent" class="draggable endEventClass"></div>

<div id="diagramZone" class="col-md-8" id="diagramZone">
</div>
```

If it don't work in the snippet, go to [This Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmalloul/zxswcjav/3/), it works perfectly

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example, however I know how to do simple drag and drop of elements, instead I have problems in managing the resizing rules of the divs I want to put in the rightdiv in order to get the page like the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If you want dragged elements to be resizable, use the `.resizable()` function, with this parameters, like this.

```
$('#startEvent').resizable({
      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
      animate: true,
      ghost: true,
      aspectRatio:true  
    });
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try to use your hint. If you or anyone have other links or tips they would be appreciated